# LWC Data Table: Hyerplink a record with lookup field

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, lookup, lightning-datatable

I am trying to add a hyperlink in my datatable to the records that are displayed. I achieved this for records that do not use a lookup field, where I can easily access each field as needed. But for a record that uses a lookup, it's trickier since I cannot use dot notation to access the needed fields here.

Each of my Job Opening object has a related list which shows each applicant, and application related to it. The applicant is a lookup field.

I am able to see all the data I need from the result object, it's just a matter of how to display it.

You can see in the screenshot that applications work just fine and I can access each one from the table, but for applicants, it does not display their names correctly, instead, it shows their IDs (I can access these records just fine too).

[image: The issue:]

```
export default class ApexDatatableExample extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

  @track columns = [
    {
      label: 'Applicant',
      fieldName: 'applicantURL',
      type: 'url',
      typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Applicant__r.Name' }, 
      target: '_blank'},
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      label: 'Application Name',
      fieldName: 'nameUrl',
      type: 'url',
      typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, 
      target: '_blank'},
      sortable: true
    },
  ]
  
  @api recordId;
  records;

  @track error;
  @track applications = [];
 
  @wire(getApps, { jobId: '$recordId'}) wiredApps(result) {
    const {data, error} = result;
    if(data) {
      let nameUrl;
      let applicantURL;
      this.applications = data.map(row => {
        nameUrl = `/${row.Id}`;
        applicantURL = `/${row.Applicant__c}`
        return {...row , nameUrl, applicantURL}
      })
      this.error = null;
    }
    if(error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.applications = [];
    }
  }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static List<Application__c> getApps(string jobId){
      return [SELECT Id,Name,Applicant__r.Name FROM Application__c 
      WHERE Applied_to_Job_Opening__c =: jobId 
      Order By Name asc];      
   }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, dot notation cannot be used so data should be flattened.
You've already done almost everything, you only need to create a new property for `applicantName` the same way you created `applicantURL` and change the columns definition to use it.

Columns:

```js
// no need to track this
columns = [
    {
      label: 'Applicant',
      fieldName: 'applicantURL',
      type: 'url',
      typeAttributes: {
        label: { fieldName: 'applicantName' },
        target: '_blank'
      },
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      label: 'Application Name',
      fieldName: 'nameUrl',
      type: 'url',
      typeAttributes: {
        label: { fieldName: 'Name' }, 
        target: '_blank'
      },
      sortable: true
    },
];
```

Wired function;

```js
@wire(getApps, { jobId: '$recordId'}) wiredApps(result) {
    const {data, error} = result;
    if(data) {
      this.applications = data.map(row => {
        const nameUrl = `/lightning/r/${row.Id}/view`;
        const applicantURL = `/lightning/r/${row.Applicant__c}/view`;
        const applicantName = row.Applicant__r.Name;
        return {...row , nameUrl, applicantURL, applicantName };
      })
      this.error = null;
    }
    if(error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.applications = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.