# LWC - Creating Datatable With Columns From Field Set -- INCLUDING Lookup Fields

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have created a LWC which displays a list of Opportunities using a Datatable. The columns shown in the Datatable are dictated by a Field Set on the Opportunity.

This is all working fine, however I'm having issues when there is a lookup field in the Field Set, e.g. AccountId or CreatedById. By default, these columns will simply output the record ID of the lookup record. What I would like to do is have it so it outputs the name of the record, with a hyperlink to the record itself (same as how the standard Related Lists work).

I have used this answer to set this up: [LWC Data Table: Hyerplink a record with lookup field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/392401/lwc-data-table-hyerplink-a-record-with-lookup-field)

This works well if you're hardcoding in the field name such as in the example above, however it doesn't work for variable field names such as in my code.

In my Apex Controller, I have the following code which attempts to dynamically generate the URL and field name for the column:

```
if(field.getType().name().toLowerCase() == 'reference'){
                System.debug('Reference Field: '+fieldPath);

                if(fieldPath.endsWith('Id')) fieldPath = fieldPath.replace('Id','.Name');
                else if(fieldPath.endsWith('__c')) fieldPath = fieldPath.replace('__c','__r.Name');

                Map<String,Object> fieldMap = new Map<String,Object>{
                    'label'=> field.getLabel(), 
                    'fieldName' => '/lightning/r/+row.'+field.getFieldPath()+'+/view', 
                    'type' => 'url', 
                    'typeAttributes' => new Map<String, Object>{
                        'label' => new Map<String, String>{
                            'fieldName' => 'row.'+fieldPath
                        },
                        'target' => '_self'
                    },
                    'sortable' => true
                };
                System.debug(fieldMap);
                columnMap.add(fieldMap);
            }
```

The columnMap Map is then returned to the LWC to be used to generate the columns of the datatable.

As you can see, I'm trying to dynamically generate the fieldName and typeAttributes.label.fieldName attributes - the idea is that the fieldName would be set to `/lightning/r/+row.'+field.getFieldPath()+'+/view`, and the typeAttributes.label.fieldName would be set to `row.fieldPath`. So, if for example the AccountId field is part of the Field Set, this would output as `/lightning/r/+row.AccountId+/view` and `row.Account.Name` respectively.

Then, the JS controller would pick this up and populate it with the Id / name when populating the datatable data:

```
@wire(GetColumnsFromFieldSet, {opportunityId:'$recordId'}) wiredColumns({error,data}){
        if (data){
            this.columns = data.map(row =>{
                return {...row};
            })
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.columns));
            //this.columns = data;
        }
        else if (error){
            window.console.log(error);
        }
        
    };

    @wire(RetrieveMatchingOpportunities, {opportunityToMatchId:'$recordId'}) wiredOpportunities({error,data}){
        if (data){
            this.data = data;
            this.data = data.map(row =>{
                return {...row};
            })
            this.sortData(this.sortedBy, this.sortDirection);
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.totalRecords = data.length;
            this.pageSize = this.pageSizeOptions[0];
            this.paginationHelper();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.data));
        }
        else if (error){
            window.console.log(error);
        }
        
    };
```

However, when I check the columns variable via console.log, this is what it outputs as:

```
[
    {
        "label": "Account ID",
        "fieldName": "/lightning/r/+row.AccountId+/view",
        "type": "url",
        "typeAttributes": {
            "label": {
                "fieldName": "row.Account.Name"
            },
            "target": "_self"
        },
        "sortable": true
    },
    {
        "label": "Created By ID",
        "fieldName": "/lightning/r/+row.CreatedById+/view",
        "type": "url",
        "typeAttributes": {
            "label": {
                "fieldName": "row.CreatedBy.Name"
            },
            "target": "_self"
        },
        "sortable": true
    }
]
```

It doesn't appear to be adding in the actual values as expected.

Has anyone else done something like this; populating the columns of a Datatable via a field set, including lookup fields? And how did you do it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detail in your question. Just to clarify, are expecting your Apex Controller to be replacing the 'row.AccountId' in the URL ('/lightning/r/+row.AccountId+/view') to be replaced with the record ID for that row?